# no recibo las cookies en mi api laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, cookies

Hola comunidad soy relativamente nuevo en Laravel, tengo una duda, ya que cree una API en Laravel que se conecta a unos archivos HTML, esta es la función del login en mi API la cual ya estuve probando en postman y funciona correctamente es por eso que crreo que el error no es la api igual la agrego para que tengan contexto de la funcion

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Autenticación exitosa
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

        // Obtener el rol del usuario
        $role = $user->role;
        $cookie = cookie('cookie_token', $token, 60 * 24);
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'token' => $token, 'role' => $role], Response::HTTP_OK)->withCookie($cookie);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Credenciales incorrectas'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

este es el login.html que e creado funciona con vue.js y axios hasta aqui la api funciona correctamente puesto en consola e logrado validar que el response si me regrese tanto el rol como el token tambien anexo el codigo como referencia y nose si aqui este el problema ya que apesar de regresarlo no veo si se guarda la cookie de token

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
        </form>
        <a href="registro.html">¿No tienes una cuenta? Regístrate aquí</a>
    </section>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Evita que se envíe el formulario de forma tradicional
    
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                credentials: 'include'
            })
            .then(response => {
                // Mostrar la respuesta de la API en la consola
                console.log(response);
                
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    // Redirigir a la página de inicio
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                } else {
                    // Si hay un error o las credenciales son incorrectas
                    alert('Correo electrónico o contraseña incorrectos');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                alert('Hubo un error al iniciar sesión');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

y tambien el de mi index que es aqui donde no recibo la cookie y por ende al querer usar la funcion de agregar al carrito no puedo validar el usuario logueado y no me guarda el registro ya que para guardar los datos necesito el id del usuario este se va null o vacio

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Página de Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.19/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <style>
  #app{
      background-color:#CFD8DC;      
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="productos.html">Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="detalle_usuario.html">Usuarios</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <h2>Productos Disponibles</h2>
        <div id="app">
            <v-app>
              <v-main>   
               <!--<h2 class="text-center">CRUD usando APIREST con Node JS</h2>-->
                <!-- Tabla y formulario -->
                <v-simple-table class="mt-5">
                    <template v-slot:default>
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="indigo darken-4">
                                <th class="white--text">ID</th>
                                <th class="white--text">NOMBRE</th>
                                <th class="white--text">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                                <th class="white--text">PRECIO</th>
                                <th class="white--text">STOCK</th>
                                <th class="white--text text-center">ACCIONES</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="articulo in articulos" :key="articulo.id">
                              <td>{{ articulo.id }}</td>
                              <td>{{ articulo.name }}</td>
                              <td>{{ articulo.description }}</td>
                              <td>{{ articulo.price }}</td>
                              <td>{{ articulo.stock }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <v-btn fab dark color="#E53935" small @click="agregar(articulo.id)"><v-icon>mdi-cart</v-icon></v-btn>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </template>
                </v-simple-table>
                </v-card>        
              <!-- Componente de Diálogo para CREAR y EDITAR -->
              </v-main>
            </v-app>
          </div>
        
          
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>© 2024 Tienda Online</p>
    </footer>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.5.7/vuetify.min.js" integrity="sha512-BPXn+V2iK/Zu6fOm3WiAdC1pv9uneSxCCFsJHg8Cs3PEq6BGRpWgXL+EkVylCnl8FpJNNNqvY+yTMQRi4JIfZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<script>
  document.cookie 
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return {            
        articulos: [],
        dialog: false,
        operacion: '',            
        articulo: {
          id: null,
          name: '',
          description: '',
          stock: '',
          price: ''  
        }          
      }
    },
    created() {               
      this.mostrar();
    },  
    methods: {          
      // Método para obtener la lista de productos desde la API
      mostrar() {

        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/articulos', { withCredentials: true })
          .then(response => {
            this.articulos = response.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error al obtener los productos:', error);
          });
      },
      // Método para agregar un producto al carrito
      agregar(id) {
        let urlAgregarCarrito = 'http://localhost:8000/api/cart-items';
        let urlActualizarStock = 'http://localhost:8000/api/products/' + id;
  
        
        // Primero, hacemos una solicitud POST para agregar el artículo al carrito
        axios.post(urlAgregarCarrito, {  product_id: id, quantity: 1 }, { withCredentials: true })
          .then(response => {
            // Si se agrega al carrito correctamente, actualizamos el stock del producto
            axios.patch(urlActualizarStock, { quantity: -1 }) // Restamos 1 al stock
              .then(response => {
                // Manejar la respuesta si es necesario
              })
              .catch(error => {
                // Manejar errores
                console.error('Error al actualizar el stock:', error);
              });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Manejar errores
            console.error('Error al agregar al carrito:', error);
          });
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

si me pudieran guiar o decir en que me equivoque les agradeceria mucho